# How to get the desired output

Tags: shell, scripting

I am getting an input from a shell script, something like:

```
USER1_OLD:USER1_NEW,USER2_OLD:USER2_NEW ....
```

The number of key pairs can vary. I need to get output like:

```
USER1_OLD,USER2_OLD,......
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What does "o/p" mean? What have you tried? Show us your script...

Answer (score 2):

One way using `awk`:

```
$ ./script.sh | awk '{printf "%s",NR==1?$1:","$1}' FS=: RS=,
USER1_OLD,USER2_OLD
```

It's not clear if you want a trailing comma, if you do the script can be simpler:

```
$ ./script.sh | awk '{print $1}' FS=: RS=, ORS=,
USER1_OLD,USER2_OLD,
```